# enums with jsonb_accessor and rails 7.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jsonb

We have an App using the `jsonb_accessor` gem.

As an example we use something like this in our project.

```rb
jsonb_accessor :user_data, gender: :string

enum gender: { male: 'male', female: 'female' }
```

After upgrading to Rails 7.1 (with this commit: https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/6c5fab0668c1872fe827507f45ef400a20e8c646) we are getting an error:

`Unknown enum attribute 'gender' for User (RuntimeError)`

Does anyone have a similar problem and found a solution for this?

Thank you in advance.

Kind regards,
pabse

Comment: I think you need to generate a github issue for the jsonb_accessor gem, which is not compatible with Rails 7.1

Comment: https://github.com/madeintandem/jsonb_accessor/issues/167

Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To complete this thread:

This feature will be added to rails again with [PR#49769](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/49769)

You just have to declare the type before.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attribute :topic, :string
  enum topic: %i[science tech engineering math]
end
```